# looping a diagonal animation

Tags: jquery, animation, loops, diagonal

I'm trying to get my spaceship to fly left and down diagonally but I can't get it to reset to do the same loop again, any help would be cool.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout("spaceship1()",400);
  });

 function spaceship1(){
     $("#spaceship1").animate({
           left:"-=800px", 
           top:"+=800px"
     },2000).animate({
           top:"-800px"
     },0);
     setTimeout("spaceship1()",2000); 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using the completion function from the animation to schedule/start the next round of animation, and please don't use strings with `setTimeout()`, use actual function references.

Your animation also doesn't cycle back to where it started so you will have to fix that to make it a complete loop.  If not, it will not return to it's original location.  I'm not sure if that is intended or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     function spaceship1() {
         $("#spaceship1").animate({
               left:"-=800px", 
               top:"+=800px"
         },2000).animate({top:"-800px"}, 2000, function() {
             setTimeout(spaceship1, 2000);
         });
     }

     setTimeout(spaceship1, 400);
});
```

Comment: @Starx - extra brace removed.